# Change the class of the span according to the text of the span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change span class according to text of span.

I tried this:

```js
$(".f1").each(function (x, span) {
    var text = $(span).html();
    if (text == 'x1') {
        $(span).addClass('badge bg-label-danger me-1').removeClass('f1');
    }
    else if (text == 'x2') {
        $(span).addClass('badge bg-label-success me-1').removeClass('f1');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="f1">x1</span>
```

Comment: Are you missing quotes around your `$(span)`? Try `$("span")`

Comment: Place the `span` element before the script.

Comment: For your use case, I'd recommend getting the `$(span).text()` instead of `$(span).html()`. But what's not working with what you're doing?

Comment: @LeoDog896 no, `span` is from `.each(function(x, span) {`

Comment: When using `.html()` or `.text()` you may also be getting whitespace - `trim()` the result:  `text = text.trim()`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
<span id="f1">x1</span>
```

```
<script>
    const span1 = document.getElementById('f1');
    const text1 = span1.textContent;
    console.log(text1);
    if (text1 == 'x1') {
        document.getElementById("f1").classList.add("badge", "bg-label-danger", "me-1");
        }
    else if (text1 == 'x2') {
        document.getElementById("f1").classList.add("badge", "bg-label-success", "me-1");
        }    
</script>
```